# No network after installing the new Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: wireless, networking, drivers, internet

Installed the new version, having trouble engaging the network. I cannot sign on to the internet. Do I need to go find the wireless adapters for my laptop?

Comment: what information does ifconfig give you?

Answer (score 0):

i had this problem fixed by : first I connected to internet with Wired Connection then i went to software & updates > Additional Drivers but i didn't find any driver there (even with searching) then , I'm updated with software updater and refer to the Software & updates again and after clicking on Additional Drivers i found the broadcom 802.11 Wireless driver and clicked on use it (it worked) , so

first go to : software & updates > Additional Drivers if you can't find driver there updater and check again !